# Type variance in multiple type instances of traits

Tags: scala, generics, multiple-inheritance, covariance, traits

Consider

```
trait Foo[+A, +B]

trait Foo1[+A] extends Foo[A, Nothing]

trait Foo2[+B] extends Foo[Nothing, B]
```

---

`new Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing]` works.

`new Foo1[Nothing] with Foo2[String]` works.

`new Foo1[String] with Foo2[String]` doesn't:

```
error: illegal inheritance;
<$anon: Foo1[String] with Foo2[String]> inherits different type instances of trait Foo:
Foo[Nothing,String] and Foo[String,Nothing]
          new Foo1[String] with Foo2[String]
              ^
```

---

It seems that in the first case, the instance is a subtype of `Foo[String, Nothing]`.

Likewise, it seems that in the second case, the instance should be a subtype of `Foo[String, String]`.

What is the difference between these two that causes only one to compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see the compiler actually explains it well:

```
: Foo1[String] with Foo2[String]> inherits different type instances of trait Foo:
Foo[Nothing,String] and Foo[String,Nothing]
              new Foo1[String] with Foo2[String]
```

To explain first one:

```
new Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing]
```

look at this example:

```
scala> val x = new Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing]
x: Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing] = $anon$1@58651fd0

scala> val y:Foo[String, Nothing] = x
y: Foo[String,Nothing] = $anon$1@58651fd0
```

As per specification, the instantiation of multiple `with` traits happen from left to right.  so first `Foo1` is instantiated. Doing `new Foo1[String]` gives you `Foo[String, Nothing]`. `with Foo2[Nothing]` gives you `Foo[Nothing, Nothing]`. Now `Foo` is co-variant for its first type parameter. In short this is valid:

```
scala> val a = new Foo[Nothing, Nothing]{}
a: Foo[Nothing,Nothing] = $anon$1@134593bf

scala> val b:Foo[String, Nothing] = a
b: Foo[String,Nothing] = $anon$1@134593bf
```

Hence you can use Foo[String, Nothing] instead of Foo[Nothing, Nothing]. This gives you ability to instantiate `y`.

In case of:

```
new Foo1[String] with Foo2[String]
```

`new Foo1[String]` gives `Foo[String, Nothing]`. `with Foo2[String]` gives `Foo[Nothing, String]`. And both of them are contradictory (due to its second parameter:

`with Foo2[String]` (Foo[Nothing, String]) becomes Foo[String, String].

```
scala> val p :Foo[String, String] = new Foo[Nothing, String]{}
p: Foo[String,String] = $anon$1@39529185
```

But *Foo[String, String] **cannot** become Foo[String, Nothing]*. (`val p :Foo[String, Nothing] = new Foo[Nothing, String]{}` fails)

Hence error.

---

**In-Variant**
If Foo is not in-variant on its first parameter, then it doesn't work:

```
scala> trait Foo[A, +B]
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Foo1[A] extends Foo[A, Nothing]
defined trait Foo1

scala> trait Foo2[+B] extends Foo[Nothing, B]
defined trait Foo2

scala> new Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing]
<console>:11: error: illegal inheritance;
 <$anon: Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing]> inherits different type instances of trait Foo:
Foo[Nothing,Nothing] and Foo[String,Nothing]
              new Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing]
```

---

**Contra-Variance**
If Foo is contra-variant on its second type, then both statements work

```
scala> trait Foo[+A, -B]
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Foo1[+A] extends Foo[A, Nothing]
defined trait Foo1

scala> trait Foo2[-B] extends Foo[Nothing, B]
defined trait Foo2

scala> new Foo1[String] with Foo2[String]
res0: Foo1[String] with Foo2[String] = $anon$1@77468bd9

scala> new Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing]
res1: Foo1[String] with Foo2[Nothing] = $anon$1@51016012
```

It simply works because now: *Foo[String, String] **can** become Foo[String, Nothing]*

Comment: "Foo[String, Nothing] does not <: Foo[String, String]" is incorrect. `new Foo[String, Nothing] {}: Foo[String, String]` works.

Comment: @PaulDraper You are doing the reverse :). It is `val v:Foo[String, Nothing] = new Foo[String, String] {}` and it fails.

Comment: @PaulDraper Yup agree. What I meant to show was co-variance relationship rather than `<:`. Mistake and hence corrected it yesterday itself